# Flutter PDF: MultiPage does not break page when content is too big

Tags: flutter, pdf

I'm making app that generates pdf resume.
I use [pdf library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf/example) to render pdf. 
The resume content is dynamic and the text could take up a lot of space.
So I need automatically break page if text is overflow.

Simplifying my code the base idea:

```dart
@override
  Future<Document> createPfd(ResumePdfCreatorParams params) async {
    final structure = params.structure;
    final seeker = FieldSeeker(structure: structure);

    final pdf = pw.Document(
      compress: false,
    )..addPage(
        pw.MultiPage(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          margin: pw.EdgeInsets.zero,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return [
              ChromaResumePage(params, seeker),
            ];
          },
        ),
      );

    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final file = File('${output.path}/example.pdf');

    await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

    return Document(
      structure: params.structure,
      path: file.path,
      name: params.template.name,
      image: '',
      templateName: params.template.name,
    );
  }
```

```dart
import 'package:cv_builder/features/document/data/field_seeker.dart';
import 'package:cv_builder/features/pdf_creator/data/resume_creators/chroma/chroma_resume_creator.dart';
import 'package:cv_builder/features/pdf_creator/models/pdf_creator_params/pdf_creator_params.dart';

// ! Pay attention I import pdf/widgets !
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

class ChromaResumePage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChromaResumePage(this.params, this.seeker);

  final ResumePdfCreatorParams params;
  final FieldSeeker seeker;
  @override
  Widget build(Context context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // lorem is a long long text that takes 2 pages
        Text(lorem),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to display text I got "TooManyPagesException" and empty page.
I tried to replace Column with Wrap, Table, ListView. I used Paragraph instead Text.
I some cases I don't receive any errors just empty page.

So how to break document into multiple pages automatically?